# Python 3.4.2 Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax-error

Im trying to build a distribution file on python.
Here is my code:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> def print_list( AList ):
        for item in AList:
           if ( isinstance( item, list )):
               print_list( item )
           else:
               print( item )
```

and here is my setup file:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> from distutils.core import setup
>>> setup(name='nester', version='1.0.0', py_modules=['nester'], author='Leo')
```

im literally performing these steps:

1. Open CMD
2. go to my folder: **"cd c:\users......\nester"** (nester is my folder)
3. write **"c:\python34\python.exe setup.py sdist"**

and it throws me an error:

File "setup.py" in line 1
Python3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9423, oct 6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
SyntaxError: **invalid sintax**

So I tried to remove the first and second line of my code in both files, and the error still there.

Any idea of what's happening?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why have you included all the interpreter boilerplate?!

Comment: If there is a more complete traceback for the error, it would help us help you.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that im new at Python, i've been reading a book about it and there is where i took the code i posted. And that's everything the book says about setup file.

Comment: Are books those things left over from the 20th century or is that something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have copy-pasted code from the python interpreter into your `setup.py` file, which brought along with it some extra junk (the interpreters status message):

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

Please remove that as well as the `>>>` markers from your `setup.py`.  In the future please note that you can not directly copy and paste from the interpreter into a `.py` file.